# How to test AWS apis from browser

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to learn various AWS apis. Do they have a web explorer where I can test the apis without writing code? Is there something similar to https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/ for Google apis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS doesn't provide an API explorer like Google.

The easiest way to play around with the API without writing code is to use the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)